# How to get Toolbar size at runtime for square camera activity

Tags: android, toolbar

I am doing an activity that wants to show a square camera. For that I add to views above the camera view. One on top and one on the bottom. Leaving just a square visible from the camera view that is below.

My problem is that to add this two view I have to calculate the size available for them but I can't get the toolbar size programmatically. No matter what I try I just get 0.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    BalrogFontsHelper.SetKhandBoldToView(toolbarTitle);
    toolbarTitle.setText(resources.getString(R.string.title_activity_camera));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_arrow_back_black_24);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
```

If I later on get the actionbar and get the height I get 0. Also from the theme I would get 0 because I use the theme Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

Getting the size of it would solve my problem but if you know better approaches to do a square camera please feel free to say also :)

The calculation of the two vies would be:

```
viewHeight = (deviceHeight-actionBarHeight)/2
```

Comment: viewHeight = (deviceHeight-deviceWidth-actionBarHeight)/2 sorry

Comment: what's wrong with toolbar.getMeasuredHeight()?

Comment: I am getting 0 too :/

Answer (score 0):

Width of the toolBar is usually "match-parent". For toolBar's height,

use `toolBar.getHeight();`

Comment: How are you implementing the toolbar in XML?

Comment: I want to put it here but is too long and I can't edit my post because I think I am too new user or something :/

But basically the toolbar height is wrap_content and it has a textview for the title that also has wrap_content.  The textview getHeight and getMeasuredHeight are giving me 0 also :/